# Python if statements and loops are a bit redundant in my connect 4 game

Tags: python

I'm doing a python class assignment but my teacher tells me that a block of my code is a bit redundant. Basically it is a connect 4 game I am building.

So this is my code, it doesn't have any errors but the block of code from the if statements is a bit redundant.

```
def draw_board(field):
    for row in field:
        for column in row:
            
            print("|" + column, end="")
       
        print("|")
Board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #0
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #1
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #2
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #3
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #4
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]] #5

Player1 = input("Enter Player: ")
Player2 = input("Enter Player: ")

turn = Player1

while True:
    print("Players Turn:", turn)
    if turn == Player1:

        SelectColumn = int(input("Select Column from 0-6: \n"))

         if Board[-1][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-1][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
         elif Board[-2][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-2][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
         elif Board[-3][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-3][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
         elif Board[-4][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-4][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
         elif Board[-5][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-5][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
         elif Board[-6][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-6][SelectColumn] = Player1
            turn = Player2
    else:
        SelectColumn = int(input("Select Column from 0-6: \n"))
         if Board[-1][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-1][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1
         elif Board[-2][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-2][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1
         elif Board[-3][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-3][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1
         elif Board[-4][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-4][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1
         elif Board[-5][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-5][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1
         elif Board[-6][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-6][SelectColumn] = Player2
            turn = Player1

draw_board(Board)
```

I was wondering, is there any way of shortening this code but still being able to accomplish the same purpose or is it okay as it is?

Comment: There is no `break` in your while True, how does it stop ? `draw_board(Board)` can never be reached and executed so

Comment: You can use a for loop as it's only the indexes that changes between all checks.

Comment: Maybe better ask this question on [codereview.se].

Comment: I've not added the break cause i want it to continue until i add the logic for checking if someone has won.

Comment: yes the players can be of any value, that's why i want a player to choose their character.

Comment: Please show me how to implement the for loops?, that was my first option.

Comment: There is a principle called DRY; Don't Repeat Yourself. you don't have to copy-paste the same code when you can use a loop or a function.

Answer (score 4):

You can do 2 things:

1. Use a `for loop`
2. Use values `1` and `-1` for the turns

Also I think you meant to put `draw_board(Board)` inside the loop.
Anyways doing the two things above can make your code much cleaner.
I also added a check so that users can't select filled columns.

```
def draw_board(field):
    for row in field:
        for column in row:
            print("|" + column, end="")
        print("|")

Board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #0
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #1
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #2
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #3
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], #4
        [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]] #5

turn = 1
Player1 = input("Enter Player: ")
Player2 = input("Enter Player: ")

while True:
    player = Player1 if turn > 0 else Player2
    print("Player's Turn:", player)
    SelectColumn = int(input("Select Column from 0-5: \n"))
    # Prevent users from selecting already filled columns
    while Board[0][SelectColumn] != " ":
        SelectColumn = int(input("Select Column from 0-6: \n"))
    
    # fill column
    for i in range(6):
        if Board[-(i + 1)][SelectColumn] == " ":
            Board[-(i + 1)][SelectColumn] = player
            break
    turn *= -1  # 'swap' players
    draw_board(Board)
    # logic for checking winner would go here
```